# OpenNLP yielding undesired result

Tags: nlp, opennlp, pos-tagger

I am using OpenNLP to process queries like "doctor working in Los Angeles" and "female living in Hollywood and working in Santa Monica". For English understanding human these sentences are very obvious that the subjects are "doctor" and "female". However when I use opennlp it tagged the sentence as

```
female_JJ living_NN in_IN hollywood_NN
```

[ female living ] [ in ] [ hollywood ]

Here's another sentence "person living in santa monica and working in malibu and playing football" was processed to be

```
person_NN living_VBG in_IN santa_NN monica_NN and_CC working_VBG in_IN malibu_NN and_CC playing_NN football_NN
 [ person ] [ living ] [ in ] [ santa monica ] and [ working ] [ in ] [ malibu and playing football ]
```

Why does OpenNLP's POS tagger tagged them wrongly? These sentences have simplest grammatical structures. If the most advanced NLP technologies still fails to parse these sentences does it mean that NLP is far from being practical currently?

Comment: Interesting example. Which OpenNLP version do you use for that, and which model files? Please provide exact references as URLs or version tags.

Comment: I was using the newest version and en-pos-maxent model. It seems Stanford Parser and NLTK are having the same problems

Comment: so, Version 1.6.0, correct?

Comment: Yes. 1.6.0 is the current version

Comment: OpenNLP is usually trained on news data, which usually contains "full" and longer sentences. Because of that OpenNLP and other off-the-shelf tools might have a hard time tagging correctly short/non-full sentences. A solution for this would be to train your own model containing this kind of data.

Comment: Training models takes lots of work. Are there any readily available solutions? Also it is hard to predict user input so the model needs be able to work with both full sentences and short sentences

Comment: "Fast, correct, universal; pick any two."

Answer (score 0):

the accuracy of all these NLP projects can not be 100%. because these projects are working on cases of probablity. these errors can be there. still then these are most accurate working results